# change position of all selected svn-elements via translate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

With a `pointermove`-event I make a svg-element dragable. After draging the new position will be saved by doing `save()'

```
canvas.on({
    'element:pointermove': function(elementView, event, x, y) {
        save();
    }
});
```

But now I want to move multiple elements: All elements I want to move have the class `highlighted`.

So with the pointermove-event I can move one element, but all other highlighted elements (if there are other highlighted elements) should do the same movement. I think I can do that with `translate()`.

But how can I 'connect' all $('.highlighted')-elements with `translate()` to make them all the same movement?

Comment: Have a look here: https://blog.jsplumbtoolkit.com/posts/multiple-element-drag.html, perhaps this library does what you need.